# Generating evenly split time stamps for every email in an array

Tags: javascript, math, intervals

I need to generate a `send_at` time that's divided evenly by the seconds in a working day 6am-6pm.

For the sake of this a list of `500` emails will be used.

```js
var emailList = ["agent0@email.com", "agent1@email.com", "agent2@email.com", ...]; //List of 500 Emails
var currentTime = new Date().getTime(); //Unix Time Stamp for right now
var day = 86400/2; //12 hours in seconds(6am-6pm)
var interval = Math.ceil(day/emailList.length); // Every 86.4 second for 500 rounded to 87
```

I just can't figure out how to get past this point.

**End Goal:** I need a function that can take an input value of an array full of emails, divide that arrays.length by the 12 hour work day of 6am-6pm, and then output an array or object of times to send each email and maybe that email as well..

**Input:** `myFuncton(emailList)`

**Output:** `[{email: "agent0@email.com", send_at: 1657559806}, {email: "agent1@email.com", send_at: 1657559893}, {email: "agent2@email.com", send_at: 1657559980}]`

Answer (score 0):

Run over the array, adding each time the interval for the timestamp.

```js
var emailList = ["agent0@email.com", "agent1@email.com", "agent2@email.com"];
var currentTime = new Date().getTime(); //Unix Time Stamp for right now
var day = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var interval = Math.ceil(day / emailList.length);

var result = [];
var send_at= currentTime;
emailList.forEach(function(email) {
  result.push({
    email: email,
    send_at: send_at,
    human_time: new Date(send_at)
  })
  send_at+= interval;
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can note the `startTime` and `endTime` of the time window and then calculate the total `timeSpan` by subtracting them. Then divide the total time by the number of emails to calculate the `intervalLength`.

From that, you can calculate the send time for each email with the formula `startTime + intervalLength * index`

```js
const emailList = Array(500).fill().map((_, i) => 'email_'+i); // Placeholder email list

const startTime = new Date().setHours(6, 0, 0, 0)
const endTime = new Date(startTime).setHours(18);

const timeSpan = endTime - startTime;
const intervalLength = timeSpan / emailList.length;

const output = emailList.map((email, i) => ({ email, send_at: startTime + intervalLength*i }));

console.log(output);
```